# Expected value of log(gamma function(Dirichlet variable))

Tags: variational-inference, multinomial-dirichlet-distribution, coordinate-descent

The following problem emerges from coordinate ascent variational inference in a mixture model with Dirichlet-Multinomial components. I want to compute the expectation of the log likelihood. Since my likelihoods are Dirichlet-Multinomials, that requires taking the expectation of a bunch of log(gamma function(random variable)) terms. How does one do this?

More specifically, let $\phi_k \sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\phi_k$ is the $k$th element of a $K$-dimensional vector $\phi$. How do I compute the following quantities?

1. $$\mathbb{E}_{\phi} \left[ \log \Gamma \left( \phi_k \right) \right] $$
2. 

$$\mathbb{E}_{\phi} \left[ \log \Gamma \left( \sum_{k=1}^K \phi_k \right) \right] $$

Comment: I don't think the first expectation has a closed form solution. Maybe Monte Carlo is a good strategy here? You can use the fact that the marginals are Beta. The second one looks easy enough though, since $\sum_{k=1}^K \phi_k=1$ is deterministic.

Comment: Actually, your question just revealed to me that I was wrong to say $\phi \sim Dirichlet$. What is a reasonable distribution to place on $\phi$ if $\phi$ is the parameter for the log likelihood?

Comment: Maybe $\phi_k$ should follow some Gamma distribution with hyperparameters $\alpha, \beta$?

Comment: If ascent is what you are after, maybe use Jensen's inequality to lower bound both of these quantities and maximize the lower bound instead?

Comment: @mhdadk maximizing that lower bound is exactly where this expected value of the log likelihood arises from

Comment: @rylanschaeffer why not maximize log(E(...)) directly if you already have it? is it not easier to compute than E(log(...)) In this case?